# How to automatically create jar in JBuilder

Tags: java, jar, jbuilder

Have a project developed in JBuilder 2007.

I can create a jar with the compiled classes and resources by right-clicking on the project in Package Explorer and selecting Export, but is there a way to set-up the project to automatically generate the jar file, whenever the source changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ant ! [Here's a link](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28934) with a great example involving jbuilder. Once your ant file is completed, you jsut run it. It will do the same thing as an export. Want any more help ?

Comment: Will be this Ant build script automatically run whenever the code changes ? Or I have to manually invoke execution of it ?

Comment: When you are ready to create the jar, you execute the build. Its manual. Eclipse, which I personnaly prefer over Jbuilder, has an option to do it automatically. Jbuilder seems to not have anything of the sort.

Comment: Finally found the same option, JBuilder can also call Ant builder when doing automatic builds: Project Properties / Builders / <your Ant builder> / Targets / Set Targets for AutoBuild.

I accept this answer, as it lead me to the solution.